# Counts[list] giving unexpected result

Tags: counting

I import some data from an .xls-file and process it by subtracting pairs of data. What I need to do is counting the total number of each difference appearing in my result list, e.g. if the result list would be {0.01, 0.02, 0.01} the output should be `0.01 -> 2` *(total amount of 2 for a-b =0.01)*, `0.02 -> 1` ...
I know there is the function `Counts[list]` for this very exact purpose, but somehow, it produces weird results:

```
Counts[{0., 0.01, 0., 0.02, -0.04, 0., 0.04, 0.02, 0.01, -0.06, 0.06, 0.02, 
0.01, -0.03, 0., -0.02, 0.01, 0., -0.03, 0., 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0., 
0., -0.02, 0., 0., 0.03, -0.01, -0.01, 0.03, -0.02, -0.01, 0.04, 
0.06, 0., 0., -0.03, 0.01, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, -0.01, 0., 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, -0.01, 0., 0.03, -0.02, -0.06, 0.01, 0., 0.01, 0.03, 
0.02, -0.02, 0.51, -0.01, 0.03, 0.06, -0.03, -0.01, -0.02, 0.01, 
-0.01, -0.02, 0., -0.05, 0.01, -0.01, 0., 0.01, 0., -0.03, 0.02, 
0.01, 0., -0.03, 0.02, -0.01, -0.01, 0.02, -0.01, 0., -0.01, -0.04, 
0., -0.03, 0., -0.02, 0.01, 0.06, 0.05, 0., -0.03, -0.02, 0.02, 0.01,
  0}
```

results in:

```
<|0. -> 23, 0.01 -> 6, 0.02 -> 2, -0.04 -> 2, 0.04 -> 1, 0.02 -> 3, 
 0.01 -> 10, -0.06 -> 2, 0.06 -> 2, 
 0.02 -> 1, -0.03 -> 1, -0.02 -> 4, -0.03 -> 1, -0.02 -> 2, 
 0.03 -> 1, -0.01 -> 9, -0.01 -> 4, 0.03 -> 3, 0.04 -> 2, 
 0.06 -> 1, -0.03 -> 1, 0.03 -> 1, 0.02 -> 4, 0.01 -> 2, -0.02 -> 3, 
 0.51 -> 1, 0.03 -> 1, -0.03 -> 3, -0.05 -> 1, 0.01 -> 1, -0.03 -> 1, 
 0.06 -> 1, 0.05 -> 1, -0.03 -> 1, 0 -> 1|>
```

which obviously is not what I intended to do. Im an absolute beginner, logged far below 10hrs into Mathematica yet, so you may excuse if my mistake is just plain stupid, Im trying my best to learn.

Comment: Could it be a precision issue with the numbers imported from excel?  If I copy your input (and add the closing bracket), the result I get is what you'd expect, without the duplicated elements.  If you put your curser on the output and start typing, do you see extra decimal places?  What about if you use `Tally`?

Comment: Try rounding or rationalizing the values before `Counts`, some of the values are not equal in all machine digits

Comment: maybe list={yourdata}; Association[
 Map[First[#]->Length[#]&, Split[Sort[Most[list]-Rest[list]]]]] which seems to produce something like what I think you are looking for

Comment: Rationalizing did work, thank you very much! Indeed, when clicking the output from `Counts[list]` the results appeared as decimals with some strange digits, hence the results even though I don't know the origin of those results. Thank you, if you would'nt mind posting an official answer I would approve and vote it. Thank you!

Comment: @Zi1mann - also try `Counts[Round[#,.0001]& /@ <your list>]`

Comment: Results in same output apparrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer, but an extended comment containing too much code and results to put in a comment.

Given your posted data, I can not reproduce your problem. The result I get looks entirely correct.

```
data = 
  {0., 0.01, 0., 0.02, -0.04, 0., 0.04, 0.02, 0.01, -0.06, 0.06, 
   0.02, 0.01, -0.03, 0., -0.02, 0.01, 0., -0.03, 0., 0.02, 0.01, 
   0.01, 0., 0., -0.02, 0., 0., 0.03, -0.01, -0.01, 
   0.03, -0.02, -0.01, 0.04, 0.06, 0., 0., -0.03, 0.01, 0.04, 0.03, 
   0.02, -0.01, 0., 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, -0.01, 0., 
   0.03, -0.02, -0.06, 0.01, 0., 0.01, 0.03, 0.02, -0.02, 0.51, -0.01,
   0.03, 0.06, -0.03, -0.01, -0.02, 0.01, -0.01, -0.02, 0., -0.05, 
   0.01, -0.01, 0., 0.01, 0., -0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0., -0.03, 
   0.02, -0.01, -0.01, 0.02, -0.01, 0., -0.01, -0.04, 0., -0.03, 
   0., -0.02, 0.01, 0.06, 0.05, 0., -0.03, -0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.};

KeySort[Counts[data]]

  <|-0.06 -> 2, -0.05 -> 1, -0.04 -> 2, -0.03 -> 8, -0.02 -> 9, 
    -0.01 -> 13, 0. -> 24, 0.01 -> 19, 0.02 -> 10, 0.03 -> 6, 
    0.04 -> 3, 0.05 -> 1, 0.06 -> 4,  0.51 -> 1|>
```

So I ask you: is the data you posted your actual data? If it is, I will vote to close the question as not reproducible.